# Is the process $\pi^{-}+p^+\to\bar{n}+n+n $ allowed?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, antimatter, baryons

Is the process $\pi^{-}+p^+\to\bar{n}+n+n $ allowed?
Is there any collision involving only the mesons and baryons that would produce antibaryons (along with other particles)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sure is allowed, conserving charge and baryon number. You can trace the valence quarks involved.

Heavy mesons, like the J/ψ [routinely](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.97.162003) decay to $p~\bar p$.